# I am working on an openCV Python program but this error keeps coming :(

Tags: python, opencv, terminal

I am working on this program in openCV in Python but this keeps coming in the terminal and crashing the program:

```
2023-12-07 22:14:20.875 Python[65850:17756657] SEEYOUDALPlugin: ObjectGetPropertyData(plugin:objectID:address:qualifiedDataSize:qualifiedData:dataSize:dataUsed:data:): Optional(1735356005)
2023-12-07 22:14:20.886 Python[65850:17756657] SEEYOUDALPlugin: Teardown(plugin:): SYLogs : TearDown
```

here's the program:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyttsx3

def get_dominant_color(frame):
    # Convert the frame from BGR to HSV color space
    hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # Define the range of the color you want to detect (in this case, red)
    lower_red = np.array([0, 100, 100])
    upper_red = np.array([10, 255, 255])

    # Create a mask to extract the color
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame, lower_red, upper_red)

    # Find contours in the mask
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    if contours:
        # Find the contour with the largest area
        largest_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
        # Find the centroid of the largest contour
        M = cv2.moments(largest_contour)
        cx = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
        cy = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

        # Get the color name based on HSV values
        color_name = get_color_name(hsv_frame[cy, cx])

        return color_name
    else:
        return None

def get_color_name(hsv_values):
    # Define the HSV ranges for different colors
    color_ranges = {
        "red": ([0, 100, 100], [10, 255, 255]),
        "green": ([40, 40, 40], [80, 255, 255]),
        "blue": ([100, 40, 40], [140, 255, 255]),
        "yellow": ([20, 100, 100], [30, 255, 255]),
        "cyan": ([85, 100, 100], [95, 255, 255]),
        "magenta": ([140, 100, 100], [150, 255, 255]),
        # Add more color ranges as needed
    }

    # Check which color range the given HSV values fall into
    for color, (lower, upper) in color_ranges.items():
        if np.all(hsv_values >= np.array(lower)) and np.all(hsv_values <= np.array(upper)):
            return color

    return "unknown"

def speak_color(color_name):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.say(f"I see the color {color_name}")
    engine.runAndWait()

def main():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if not ret:
            print("Error reading frame")
            break

        color_name = get_dominant_color(frame)

        if color_name:
            speak_color(color_name)

        cv2.putText(frame, f"Color: {color_name}", (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

        cv2.imshow("Camera Feed", frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: Can you `print()` this? `color_name = get_dominant_color(frame)`